# When using a RegExp replace within a chrome.tabs.query error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

this is my content.js file, and when I try to get it to censor the word "cake" to "****" it gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've got a feeling it's got something to do with callbacks but I'm quite unsure.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
var removeProf = document.getElementById('removeProf');
var fourmTabs = new Array();


removeProf.onclick = function(element) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        fourmTabs[i] = tabs[i];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++) {
        if (fourmTabs[i] != null)
        {
           window.console.log(fourmTabs[i].url);
        }

        else {
            window.console.log("??" + i);
        }
        // For loop to apply the cake censor
        for (var i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++)
        {
            var webURL2 = fourmTabs[i];
            var sC = webURL2.innerHTML;
            var pattern = new RegExp(/cake/gi);
            sC = sC.replace(pattern,'\*\*\*\*')
            tabs[i].innerHTML = sC; 


        }
    }
});}}
```

Comment: A tab object doesn't have innerHTML. A content script isn't just a file that's named "content.js", it's a separately executed script, not something you load via `script` tag in popup.html. Example: [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/11696154)

Comment: Hey, I know about the content thing, I've got it in my permissions and on the html just after the body. But with the other point you had, would you say doing it the way through that example is the best way? I'm just looking for a function to find and replace on all webpages

Comment: An instance of content script runs alongside each web page in its process, you can't access it directly from an extension page such as popup.